# Fastest grep to search string on zip files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, centos

I have a list of upto 50K names. That I need to search that in logs, those are in multiple zip files. These zip files are in diffrent folders and huge (upto 450GB). and there are multiple files in a zip file.

Right now I am iterating on each zip file and each file's log files and searching names in them.

```
cd /disk1/ABCDEFArchive/

while read pl; do
  echo Searching $pl

  for i in 3 3-AB 3-CD 3-EF 4 4-AB 4-CD 4-EF 5 5-AB 5-CD 5-EF 
  do
    cd web$i
    for j in 2017-09 2017-10 2017-11 2017-12 2017-01 2017-02 
    do
      for k in $(unzip -l ABCDEF-${j}.zip | awk '{print $4}' | grep ABCDEF)
      do
        echo "searching $pl in   web$i ===>>> ABCDEF-${j}.zip ===>>> $k  "
        isexists=$(unzip -p ABCDEF-${j}.zip $k  | grep "=${pl}" | head -1 )
        if [[ ! -z "$isexists" ]]; then
          mysql -e "update test.product_list_tobedeleted set foundinlogs=1 where list_name =\"${pl}\";"
      echo "$pl@@@$isexists" >>${ScriptPath}/ProductlistFound.csv
          break 3   
        fi
     done
   done 
   cd ..
  done
```

But it is working very slow since one month and still at 3000's name

I also tried few more work arrounds like to find in zip file witout iterating in each log file etc. but those are even worse.

Comment: I guess you're CPU limited (due to decompressing so much data).  The only thing you can do is parallelize (run chunks of the outer loop in separate background processes).

Comment: Parallal search wont work or will rework. Because if a name is found in a file. It will skip on all serachis